Loop on Shiny to get multiple output
I made an NPC Generator Shiny WebApp for some TTRPG, but at the moment it can only generate one NPC at a time. I would like to make it so that users can select how many NPC they want to generate and the WebApp would simply loop for the input number and render all the results directly one after the other.
But I don't know how to do it. I suppose a FOR loop or using APPLY/LAPPLY would be the way but I'm completely at loss on how to use them in general, even more so in shiny.
Could any of you help me on that matter? Here's the script and a link to the app:
https://forges-imaginaire.shinyapps.io/Avatar-Legends-NPC-Generator/
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinythemes)

# Mise en place -----------------------------------------------------------
list_names <- read.csv2("list_names.csv",
                        fileEncoding = "Windows-1252",
                        check.names=F)

list_techniques<- read.csv2("list_techniques.csv",
                            fileEncoding = "Windows-1252", 
                            check.names=F)

list_principles_drives <- read.csv2("list_principles_drives.csv", 
                                    fileEncoding="Windows-1252", 
                                    check.names=F)

list_caracteristics <- read.csv2("list_caracteristics.csv", 
                                 fileEncoding="Windows-1252", 
                                 check.names=F)

list_hair <- read.csv2("list_hair.csv", 
                       fileEncoding="Windows-1252", 
                       check.names=F)

# Define UI for application ----
ui <- fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("journal"),
                
                # Application title
                titlePanel("Avatar Legends - NPC Generator (V2) "),
                
                # Topbar with selections 
                fluidRow(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                         id = "side-panel",
                         column(2,radioButtons("choice_type","NPC Types", c("Minor NPC",
                                                                            "Major NPC",
                                                                            "Master NPC",
                                                                            "Group")),
                                sliderInput("num_npc","Number of NPC",value=1,
                                            min = 1, max = 15),
                                offset=1),
                         
                         column(2,radioButtons("choice_gender", "Gender/Sex", c("Male",
                                                                                "Female",
                                                                                "Random"))),
                         
                         column(2,selectInput("choice_nation", "Nation", c("Air Nomads",
                                                                           "Earth Kingdom",
                                                                           "Fire Nation",
                                                                           "Republic City",
                                                                           "Water Tribe",
                                                                           "Random"))),
                         
                         column(2,selectInput("choice_training", "Training", c("Airbending",
                                                                               "Earthbending",
                                                                               "Firebending",
                                                                               "Martial Art",
                                                                               "Technology",
                                                                               "Universal",
                                                                               "Waterbending",
                                                                               "Group",
                                                                               "No Training",
                                                                               "Random"))),
                         
                         column(2, sliderInput("num_tech","Number of techniques",value=1,
                                               min = 0, max = 5),
                                selectInput("special_tech","Specialized Bending", c("---",
                                                                                    "Bloodbending",
                                                                                    "Combustionbending",
                                                                                    "Healing",
                                                                                    "Lavabending",
                                                                                    "Lightningbending",
                                                                                    "Metalbending",
                                                                                    "Seismic Sense")),
                                
                                selectInput("rare_tech","Rare Techniques",c("No", "Yes"))),
                         
                         
                         fluidRow(column(2,actionButton("generate","Generate"),
                                         offset= 4),
                                  column(2,actionButton("generate_random","Random")),
                                  column(2,actionButton("reset_input", "Reset")))),
                
                
                mainPanel(fluidRow(htmlOutput("NPC")),
                          fluidRow(htmlOutput("tech")),
                          fluidRow(htmlOutput("NPC_random")),
                          fluidRow(htmlOutput("tech_random")),
                          offset=2
                          
                )
)


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  NPC <- eventReactive(input$generate,{
    
    type <- input$choice_type
    
    gender <- if(type!="Group"){
      case_when(input$choice_gender == "Male" ~ "Male",
                input$choice_gender == "Female" ~ "Female",
                input$choice_gender == "Random" ~ sample(c("Male","Female"),1))}
    
    nation <- if(type!="Group"){
      case_when(input$choice_nation ==  "Air Nomads" ~ "Air Nomads" ,
                input$choice_nation ==  "Earth Kingdom" ~ "Earth Kingdom",
                input$choice_nation ==  "Fire Nation" ~ "Fire Nation",
                input$choice_nation ==  "Republic City" ~ "Republic City",
                input$choice_nation ==   "Water Tribe" ~ "Water Tribe",
                input$choice_nation ==  "Random" ~ sample(c("Air Nomads",
                                                            "Earth Kingdom",
                                                            "Fire Nation",
                                                            "Republic City",
                                                            "Water Tribe"),1))}
    
    number_tech <- input$num_tech
    
    name <- if(type!="Group"){
      list_names %>% 
        filter(sex==input$choice_gender) %>% 
        sample_n(1) %>% 
        pull(nation)}
    
    
    fatigue <- case_when(type=="Minor NPC" ~ sample(2:6, 1),
                         type=="Major NPC"~ sample(5:9, 1),
                         type=="Master NPC"~ sample(8:13, 1),
                         type=="Group" ~ sample (2:13, 1))
    
    principle <- list_principles_drives %>% 
      select(Principles) %>% 
      sample_n(1) %>% 
      pull(Principles)
    
    drive <- list_principles_drives %>% 
      select(Drives) %>% 
      sample_n(1) %>% 
      pull(Drives)
    
    background <- if(type!="Group"){sample(c("Military","Monastic", "Outlaw",
                                             "Privileged","Urban","Wilderness"), 2)}
    
    size <- if(type!="Group"){
      c(round(runif(n=1, min=1.2, max=2),2), "m, ")}
    
    weight<-if(type!="Group"){c(sample(50:130, 1), "kg,")}
    
    hair <- if(type!="Group"){list_hair %>% 
        select(Hair) %>% 
        sample_n(1)}
    
    if(type!="Group" & input$choice_gender=="Male"){
      facial_hair<-list_hair %>% 
        select(Facial_Hair) %>% 
        sample_n(1)
    }
    else{facial_hair<-c(" ")}
    
    demeanor<-if(type!="Group"){ list_caracteristics %>% 
        select(Demeanor)}
    demeanor_sample1<-if(type!="Group"){sample(1:100, 1)}
    demeanor_sample2<-if(type!="Group"){sample(101:200,1)}
    
    physical_quirk <- if(type!="Group"){list_caracteristics %>% 
        select(Physical_quirk) %>% 
        sample_n(1)}
    
    behavior_quirk <- if(type!="Group"){list_caracteristics %>% 
        select(Behavior_quirk) %>% 
        sample_n(1)}
    
    accessories <- if(type!="Group"){list_caracteristics %>% 
        select(Accessories) %>% 
        sample_n(1)}
    
    paste("<h2>",name," - ", type,"</h2>", 
          "<h3>",nation,"</h3>",
          "<p><b>Gender :</b>", gender,
          "<p> <b>Principle :</b>", principle,
          "<br> <b>Drive :</b>", drive,
          "<p> <b>Background :</b>", background[1],"/",background[2],
          "<br><b>Demeanor :</b>", demeanor[demeanor_sample1,],"/",
          demeanor[demeanor_sample2,],
          "<br><b>Physique :</b>", size[1],size[2],weight[1],weight[2],
          hair,facial_hair,physical_quirk,
          "<br><b>Quirk :</b>",behavior_quirk,
          "<br><b>Accessory :</b>",accessories,
          "<p> <b>Fatigue :</b>", fatigue,
          "<h3>Technique(s)</h3>")
    
  })
  
  output$NPC <- renderText({
    NPC()
  })
  
  tech<-eventReactive(input$generate,{
    
    training_choice <- case_when(input$choice_training == "Airbending" ~ "Airbending" ,
                                 input$choice_training == "Earthbending" ~ "Earthbending",
                                 input$choice_training == "Firebending" ~ "Firebending",
                                 input$choice_training == "Martial Art" ~ "Martial Art",
                                 input$choice_training == "Waterbending" ~ "Waterbending",
                                 input$choice_training == "Technology" ~ "Technology",
                                 input$choice_training == "Universal" ~ "Universal",
                                 input$choice_training == "No Training" ~ "No Training",
                                 input$choice_training == "Group" ~ "Group",
                                 input$choice_training == "Random" ~ sample(c("Airbending",
                                                                              "Earthbending",
                                                                              "Firebending",
                                                                              "Martial Art",
                                                                              "Technology",
                                                                              "Universal",
                                                                              "Waterbending",
                                                                              "No Training"),1))
    
    if(input$rare_tech == "No"){
      techniques <- list_techniques %>% 
        filter(Training %in% training_choice,
               Specialized==input$special_tech | Specialized=="---",
               Rare!="Yes") %>% 
        slice_sample(n=input$num_tech) %>% 
        pull(Technique)
      
      paste(techniques)
    }
    else{    
      techniques <- list_techniques %>% 
        filter(Training %in% training_choice,
               Specialized==input$special_tech  | Specialized=="---") %>% 
        slice_sample(n=input$num_tech) %>% 
        pull(Technique)
      
      paste(techniques)}
    
  })
  
  output$tech <- renderText({
    tech()
  })  
   
  observeEvent(input$reset_input, {
    shinyjs::reset("side-panel")
    shinyjs::hide("NPC")
    shinyjs::hide("tech")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$generate, {
    shinyjs::show("NPC")
    shinyjs::show("tech")
  })
  
}

# Run the application ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

EDIT
I tried using a FOR loop by creating a list for each component of the NPC description, then gather them all into one list of lists and paste the whole thing. I've gotten an Error in [[ : subscript out of bonds
here's the code :
  
  NPC <- eventReactive(input$generate,{
    
    number_npc <- input$num_npc
    list_npc <- list()
    list_name <- list()
    list_type <-list()
    list_gender<-list()
    list_nation <- list()
    list_tech <- list()
    liste_name <- list()
    list_fatigue <- list()
    list_principle <- list()
    list_drive <- list()
    list_background <- list()
    list_size <- list()
    list_weight<-list()
    list_hair <- list()
    list_physical <- list()
    list_behavior <- list()
    list_accessory <-  list()
    
    for(i in 1:number_npc){
      list_type[[i]] <- input$choice_type
      
      list_gender[[i]] <- if(input$choice_type!="Group"){
        case_when(input$choice_gender == "He/Him" ~ "He/Him",
                  input$choice_gender == "She/Her" ~ "She/Her",
                  input$choice_gender == "They/Them" ~ "They/Them",
                  input$choice_gender == "Random" ~ sample(c("Male","Female"),1))}
      
      list_nation[[i]] <- if(input$choice_type!="Group"){
        case_when(input$choice_nation ==  "Air Nomads" ~ "Air Nomads" ,
                  input$choice_nation ==  "Earth Kingdom" ~ "Earth Kingdom",
                  input$choice_nation ==  "Fire Nation" ~ "Fire Nation",
                  input$choice_nation ==  "Republic City" ~ "Republic City",
                  input$choice_nation ==   "Water Tribe" ~ "Water Tribe",
                  input$choice_nation ==  "Random" ~ sample(c("Air Nomads",
                                                              "Earth Kingdom",
                                                              "Fire Nation",
                                                              "Republic City",
                                                              "Water Tribe"),1))}
      
      list_tech[[i]] <- input$num_tech
      
      list_name[[i]] <- if(input$choice_type!="Group"){
        df_names %>% 
          filter(sex==input$choice_gender) %>% 
          sample_n(1) %>% 
          pull(nation)}
      
      
      list_fatigue[[i]] <- case_when(input$choice_type=="Minor NPC" ~ sample(2:6, 1),
                                     input$choice_type=="Major NPC"~ sample(5:9, 1),
                                     input$choice_typetype=="Master NPC"~ sample(8:13, 1),
                                     input$choice_typetype=="Group" ~ sample (2:13, 1))
      
      list_principle[[i]] <- df_principles_drives %>% 
        select(Principles) %>% 
        sample_n(1) %>% 
        pull(Principles)
      
      list_drive[[i]] <- df_principles_drives %>% 
        select(Drives) %>% 
        sample_n(1) %>% 
        pull(Drives)
      
      list_background[[i]] <- if(input$choice_type!="Group"){sample(c("Military","Monastic", "Outlaw",
                                                                      "Privileged","Urban","Wilderness"), 2)}
      
      list_size[[i]] <- if(input$choice_type!="Group"){
        c(round(runif(n=1, min=1.2, max=2),2), "m, ")}
      
      list_weight[[i]]<-if(input$choice_type!="Group"){c(sample(50:130, 1), "kg,")}
      
      list_hair[[i]] <- if(input$choice_type!="Group"){
        df_hair %>% 
          select(Hair) %>% 
          sample_n(1)}
      
      if(input$choice_type!="Group" & input$choice_gender=="Male"){
        facial_hair<-df_hair %>% 
          select(Facial_Hair) %>% 
          sample_n(1)
      }
      else{facial_hair<-c(" ")}
      
      demeanor<-if(input$choice_type!="Group"){ df_caracteristics %>% 
          select(Demeanor)}
      demeanor_sample1<-if(input$choice_type!="Group"){sample(1:100, 1)}
      demeanor_sample2<-if(input$choice_type!="Group"){sample(101:200,1)}
      
      list_physical[[i]]<- if(input$choice_type!="Group"){df_caracteristics %>% 
          select(Physical_quirk) %>% 
          sample_n(1)}
      
      list_behavior[[i]] <- if(input$choice_type!="Group"){df_caracteristics %>% 
          select(Behavior_quirk) %>% 
          sample_n(1)}
      
      list_accessory[[i]] <- if(input$choice_type!="Group"){df_caracteristics %>% 
          select(Accessories) %>% 
          sample_n(1)}
      
      list_npc[[i]] <- c(    list_name[[i]],
                             list_type[[i]],
                             list_gender[[i]],
                             list_nation[[i]],
                             list_tech[[i]],
                             liste_name[[i]],
                             list_fatigue[[i]],
                             list_principle[[i]],
                             list_drive[[i]] ,
                             list_background[[i]] ,
                             list_size[[i]] ,
                             list_weight[[i]],
                             list_hair[[i]] ,
                             list_physical[[i]],
                             list_behavior[[i]],
                             list_accessory[[i]] )
      paste(list_npc[i]) 
    }
    

  })
  
  output$NPC <- renderUI({
    NPC()
  })```


Hi, welcome to SO. your code is not reproducible, please read this and try to provide an example by breaking down your code to the minimal necessary to reproduce the error. This will also help other users with the same error to quickly identify if they have the same issue or not.
